# New notifications not showing after one has been swiped away

Tags: android, notifications

My android app tracks the user's location and compares it to the locations in a list, and if it finds a match, it creates a heads-up notification that remains visible at the top of the screen (the green band in this image).

[image]
Then if the user taps the notification, it starts another activity (DisplayActivity) using a pendingIntent. This process may be repeated many times in a journey, with a new notification for each one.

Here is my code:

```
void makeNotification() {
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int soundName;
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "AMJnotifychannel";
        Intent goShow = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
        goShow.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        goShow.putExtra("placeno", placeNumber);
        goShow.putExtra("plname", placeName);
        goShow.putExtra("justquiz", quizOnly);
        goShow.putExtra("addedscore", scoreAdded);
        goShow.putExtra("killlquiz", false);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationNumber, goShow, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.expandednotify);
        expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.placename, placeName);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        soundName = R.raw.alert;
        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + soundName);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "amjchannel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes);
        channel.shouldVibrate();
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC); 
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        builder.setSound(sound);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.amjnotify);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setCustomContentView(expandedView);
        builder.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        builder.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationManager.notify(717, builder.build());
    }
}
```

As long as the user does tap the notification each time and starts DisplayActivity, this works fine - new notifications continue to appear as a heads-up notifications at the top of the screen and the user doesn't have to open the notification drawer to see them.

However, if at any time the user dismisses a notification by swiping it upwards and off the screen, the next time a notification occurs it behaves differently. Swiping a notification away into the drawer just once means that, after that, all future notifications no longer appear at the top of the screen automatically - they go straight into the drawer and the user then has to open the drawer to see them.

I have tried this on a number of Android builds using emulators - API28, API29, API30 and API33 - always with the same result.

These notifications are essential to my app, which is useless without them. Can anyone tell me how to make sure that new notifications appear on the screen every time, as in the picture, even after the user has swiped one away into the notification drawer.

And just to make the puzzle more complicated..........

I have just tried deleting the old notification using:

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(717);
```

before creating a new one. As before, everything is ok if the user taps the notification and opens the new activity each time. However, if he swips the notification away one time, then whenever there is another notification after that it goes straight to the displayActivity without waiting for the user to tap the intent.

I'm totally confused!